# Array of objects to map

Tags: arrays, reactjs, components, map-function

Could anybody tell me where i am going wrong?
I have a sample code [here](https://codesandbox.io/s/compassionate-wildflower-8dqxr?file=/src/Contact.js) where i am mapping over an array of objects and trying to render each item but for some reason it renders the same thing the amount of times of how many items I have.
Take a look at my code and pls tell me how to solve this.
What i am trying to achieve is to have the

#### Contact

as a title and then phone and email to be each rendered once with their corresponding item.

Hope you understand what i mean :)
Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You were initializing objects in `contact` array wrongly.

Here is how you should initialize:-

```
this.state = {
      contact: [{ phone: "000000", email: "bla@bla.com" }]
    };
```

Comment: OMG Thank you! i don't know how i didn't think at this before. Facepalm :)